# Store an unique data which has two attributes into the database table?

Tags: database

Like my school has longitude and latitude, do I need to create a new table for it ?

Or I just combine these two values into a string then insert this string into an existed key and value pairs setting table??

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you need to use it later. If you need the latitude and longitude in some logical processing then it is advised to store them separately in two columns. But if you need to just show it some where (eg school info page) then you can store them together as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would store them appart... and I would consider making them primary keys too.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to have them in separate columns as these values will be used for calculations.